# Creating Folders To organize Templates in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: content-type, folder, document-template

I have a library with a large number of custom document templates which I would like to organize based on type of document.  As of now, users choose the document from the drop down under new document, but I am wondering if there is a way to organize this list with folders?  Any help with this would be great!

Comment: Did you mean folders in the menu?

Comment: @alexey yes.  Folders within the New Document menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can easily achieve exactly that, but you can assign different content type orders to different folders so that inside each folder the menu is by far less cluttered and appropriate documents go to appropriate folders.

Use "content type order" in the context menus that pop up on folders.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  As a follow up:  So my scenario is a bunch of different documents being created by multiple departments, each department has their own notes to create, but they all need to be stored centrally.  There are 30+ templates in the "New Document" drop down menu, and im hoping to declutter that.  Is there a way to auto transfer documents into a library once created?

Comment: Yes, if you employ the Content Organizer feature and ensure that documents are tagged consistently by the users.